# A way to remove specific characters from a string? (kotlin)

Tags: android, string, replace, kotlin, char

So I have a textField where you should enter your "coded" text and get it translated back to non-coded language by using .replace to remove certain characters. But I can't get it to work.

There is a kids "code-language" where you take a word, like cat and for every consonant you add an "o" and the consonant again. So a "b" would be "bob". With vowels they just stay as they are. Cat would be cocatot.

```
fun translateBack(view : View) {
     val konsonanter = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ"
     var input = editText.text.toString()
     var emptyString = ""

     for(i in konsonanter) {
        val find_text = i + "o" + i

        var conso = i.toString()

        textView.text = input.replace(find_text, conso, false)
     }
 }
```

Would like for it to remove the two following letters for every consonant (if possible). So if i enter "cocowow" I should get out "cow". Right now I just get back what I enter in the textField...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're setting the text in `textView` in every loop, and never updating `input`. So you're essentially only seeing the result of the `replace` call that happens with the `"ZoZ"` and `"Z"` parameters at the end of the loop, with `input` still being the original string.

Instead, you can keep updating `input` and then set the text when you're done:

```
val konsonanter = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ"
var input = editText.text.toString()
var emptyString = ""

for (i in konsonanter) {
    val find_text = i + "o" + i

    val conso = i.toString()

    input = input.replace(find_text, conso, false)
}

textView.text = input
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `forEach` loop through the chars of `input` and replace:

```
konsonanter.forEach { input = input.replace("${it}o${it}", "${it}", false) }
textView.text = input
```

Comment: I don't know if OP needs it, but this would not work for "Bob" (uppercase B at the start). I addressed that in my answer.

Comment: @WilliMentzel if `input` is **"Bob"** then the result is **"Bob"** also because of `false` for the `ignoreCase` argument. Why do you say that this would not work for "Bob"?

Comment: shouldn't  "Bob" be turned to "b"? maybe I misunderstood it

Comment: No, "bob" should be turned to "b" and "BoB"  should be turned to "B".

Comment: maybe you know this game better than I do, I don't think it's clear from the question... who knows. good answer anyways.

Comment: I never heard of this game before. I just guessed by the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [replace](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html) function with a Regex and a transform function as parameters you can create a really concise completely self-containing extension function:

```
fun String.translateBack() = with(Regex("([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz])o\\1", RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)) {
    replace(this) { "${it.value.first()}" }
}
```

**Explanation:**

The Regex will match all same consonants (no matter the case) around an "o".
To ensure that the consonant before and after the "o" are the same a [backreference](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html) to the first group was used.

So, this will also work for cases like "coCatot".

**Usage:**

```
println("bob".translateBack()) // b
println("cocatot".translateBack()) // cat
println("coCatot".translateBack()) // cat
```